# in cakephp how to create another file like core.php file and call global variable in js file

Tags: javascript, php, config, cakephp-2.3

I have created a file inside config folder similar like config.php.
how can I call the global variables mentioned in my newconfigfile.php in my js file.
for example define("DATETIME_FORMAT", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm");

Comment: can you explain briefly

Comment: I need to create one more file similar like core.php in cakephp and want to add my global variable in new file. 
and I want to call that global variable in my js file..

like in core.php  i write define("DATETIME_FORMAT", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"); 
and in js i use DATETIME_FORMAT to format date

Comment: first you make constant.php file where you can declare your global variable

Comment: define('DATETIME_FORMAT', 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm'); in costant.php call this file to bootstrap.php require_once('constant.php');

Comment: and call your global variable to anywhere

Comment: I have already tried this and this is not working . i think we need to call the constant.php somewhere

Comment: this code is working on my webapplication

Answer (score 0):

Create a fie in your ***app/Vendor/newconfigfile.php*** then paste this line

```
define("DATETIME_FORMAT", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
```

Now go to in your ***app/Config/bootstrap.php***

Add the following line

```
App::import('Vendor', 'newconfigfile');
```

Now you can call `DATETIME_FORMAT` as a global variable.